# WebStorm JSDoc class declaration for code completion with node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jsdoc

I'd like to know how to correctly use JSDoc in WebStorm 11 to mark classes and types in a node.js application to get code completion etc.

Example:

file A:

```
function A(){
    this.b = true;
}
A.prototype.doSth = function doSth() {
    return !this.b;
}
module.export = new A();
```

file B:

```
var foo = bar(); // returns type of A
```

Now I'd like to have code completion for "foo.", so that it suggests foo.b, foo.doSth, ...

I tried a lot of JSDoc entries like @class, @constructor and used @type {A} to define type of foo like

```
/* @type {A} */
var foo = bar();
```

but WebStorm does not recognize the type A. it does no code completion and also Ctrl+Click on the type A in brackets says "Cannot find declaration to go to".

Any idea how to do this correctly?

Comment: You need using @module tag and refer to your modules using module: namepath. See http://usejsdoc.org/howto-commonjs-modules.html

Comment: Thanks @lena! That got me closer, but still not exactly where I want, maybe I misunderstood something:

Using
`/**
 * @module test/data/A
 */
module.exports = new A();`

It did not work as expected. But when I add
` @alias module:test/data/A.doSth`
In front of every single function added to prototype of A it works to have code completion. But I would like to avoid this. Is there a way to make it detect this automatically?

Comment: Also see this related question, but for ES6 classes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46504694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution. The problem was just the Syntax I used to mark the variable type:

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function A(){
    this.b = true;
}
A.prototype.doSth = function doSth() {
    return !this.b;
}
module.export = new A();
```

Works with

```
/**
 * @type {A}
 */
var foo = bar();
```

Notice the difference in the comment syntax:
Previously I tried to use

```
/* @type {A} */
var foo = bar();
```

Which does not work. `@class` can also be exchanged with `@constructor`

Comment: If you can, I recommend upgrading to a newer Node.js version supporting ES6. See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46504694